# Change prompt when starting a terminal from bash script (but don't affect all terminals)

Tags: environment-variables, path, prompt, gnome-terminal, xfce4-terminal

I have two terminals installed, `gnome-terminal` and `xfce4-terminal`.

I would like to have only the xfce terminal showing a simple `>` as prompt when I start it. The `gnome-terminal` prompt should remain unchanged (so no `bashrc` modification, I think).

I don't mind starting `xfce-terminal` from a script or another terminal with some parameters.

I tried:

```
xfce4-terminal -x export PS1='> '
```

but that throws an error and is apparently not do-able.

Any solution is welcome, even if it's a bit hackish

Answer (score 1):

Do change your `.bashrc`, and test the name of the parent process.

```
parent_process=$(ps -o comm= -p $PPID)
parent_process=${parent_process##*/}
case "$parent_process" in
  xfce4-terminal) PS1='> ';;
esac
```

Another method would be to set an environment variable: run `PROMPT_THEME=plain xfce4-terminal` and test the value of `PROMPT_THEME` in your `.bashrc`. You may want to unset or at least unexport the variable there, as otherwise it will also be set in terminals started from within that first one.

```
case $PROMPT_THEME in
  plain) PS1='> ';;
esac
export -n PROMPT_THEME
```

With `xfce4-terminal`, this won't work except for the first instance, because subsequent instances merely notify the running instance to open a new window, so new instances inherit the environment from the running one. (Yeech!) You can instead set the environment variable through the command that you start in the terminal, with the `env` utility.

```
xfce4-terminal -x env PROMPT_THEME=plain bash
```

Comment: +1 for the `PROMPT_THEME` suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Check which terminal is being opened:

```
 case "$TERM" in
    gnome-terminal ) PS1="[\h] \W > \[\033]0;[\u@\h] \w\007\]"
        ;;
    xfce4-terminal ) PS1="> "
        ;;
    esac
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried your code at the bottom of my `.bashrc` and rebooted. It had no effect (although I'm not sure why seems like it should work).

Comment: `gnome-terminal` and `xfce-terminal` are not valid value for $TERM i don't believe. Look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/233280/gnome-terminal-reports-term-to-be-xterm suggests checking $COLORTERM . i have not tested

Comment: @Juicy I don't have accesss to either terminal; but according to Petey T's link you should be able to change `"$TERM"` to `"$COLORTERM"`... To be sure, `echo "$TERM"` in both terminals.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to start with the current BASH PID (you get it with $$) and then get the PPID, and so on, until you find what terminal is the ancestor of the bash shell. Based on that information then you set the PS.

Usually the parent of the shell will be the terminal

Proof of concept in my system (Debian 7).

```
$ PARENT_PID=$(ps --pid=$$ -o ppid --no-headers)
$ ps --pid $PARENT_PID -o command --no-headers
gnome-terminal -x /bin/sh -c cd '/home/XXXX/Desktop' && exec $SHELL
```

So, in my system is enough to look to the shell's parent to find that it is being run from a gnome terminal.

Condensed in one line:

```
$ ps --pid $(ps --pid=$$ -o ppid --no-headers) -o command --no-headers
gnome-terminal -x /bin/sh -c cd '/home/XXXX/Desktop' && exec $SHELL
```

I tried and added this line to my `.bashrc`

```
MY_TERMINAL=$(ps --pid $(ps --pid=$$ -o ppid --no-headers) -o command --no-headers | cut -f 1 -d " ")
```

And I verified that `MY_TERMINAL` contains `gnome-terminal`.

So, that should do it.

Comment: Why are you looking at the grandparent of the shell? The terminal emulator is the parent of the shell, unless there's some weirdness in your configuration that causes an intermediate process. In a normal setup, the grandparent will be the window manager or whatever started the terminal emulator.

Comment: You are right. Commands were OK but naming was wrong. It should say parent not grandparent. Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your `~/.bashrc` doesn't set `PROMPT_COMMAND`, you can start `xfce4-terminal` as:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="> "; unset PROMPT_COMMAND' xfce4-terminal
```